# initial a (N+1)-D array from a N-D array with a "value to 1-D array" function

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a function to convert a value to a list (or array). How can I use it to convert a N-D array to another (N+1)-D array? The code below needs to generate a list then convert to <numpy.ndarray>. I'm wonder if there is a more efficient way (maybe some constructor for <numpy.ndarray>?).

```
# # assume we have a function foo
# def foo(val):
#     return [val*10, val*20 - 7]
# # how can we use this function to convert a N-D array to another (N+1)-D array?
# # here is my tried 

import numpy as np
def foo(val):
    return [val*10, val*20 - 7]

a = np.arange(3) # 'numpy.ndarray', [0 1 2]
b = [foo(val) for val in a]

print (type(b)) # not good, it is a 'list'
print (b) # [[0, -7], [10, 13], [20, 33]]

b = np.array(b).reshape((3, 2))
print (type(b)) # this is what I want 'numpy.ndarray'
print (b) # will be what I want:
          # [[ 0 -7]
          #  [10 13]
          #  [20 33]]
```

If there is no <numpy.ndarray> constructor for this. Should I generate a new ndarray (maybe with "numpy.zeros") and fill the value? Or it is recommend to generate a list then convert it to a ndarray? Not sure which one is faster.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly return a numpy array from your function:

```
def foo(val):
    return np.column_stack((val*10, val*20 - 7))
```

Because `val*10` invokes elementwise multiplication (special case of numpy broadcasting), the result will be another array of the same shape. The same applies to  `val*20 - 7`. Then `column_stack()` just attaches the two arrays together to get the final output shape you want.

For the general case (N-D to (N+1)-D), you can use:

```
def foo(val):
    return np.stack((val*10, val*20 - 7), axis=-1)
```

which will stack your N-D arrays into a (N+1)-D array along the last dimension.

Comment: Good point! I just tried and I found it works on 1-D array to 2-D array. However if the val is 2-D array the foo function won't return a 3-D array, still studying why...

Comment: @GarlicTseng I edited the answer for the general N-D case